# Will a scheduled task be blocked if another user is logged in?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task set to run when logged on or off, and it seems to work, but if a different user is logged into the machine (the machine is on a domain, so a different domain user), will the task still run, or will this log-on prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task will run. It will use the credentials supplied when it was created. The other user being logged on will have no affect whatsoever.